# Script para menu lateral

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, jquery-plugins

Alguém conhece algum script para fazer um menu lateral responsivo parecido com aquele do badoo??
Quando estiver vendo o site em um dispositivo com tela grande o menu aparece com todas as opções e qd estiver numa tela menor o menu se esconde mostrando apenas ícones com das opções.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você também pode usar o Material Design Lite do Google. Na sua página de template tem um exemplo com menu lateral responsivo.

Link com alguns template
https://getmdl.io/templates/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar usar o [materialize](http://materializecss.com/), ele é totalmente responsivo e com opções para criar esse menu responsivo que você quer.
 Por exemplo, você poderia fazer dois menus(um para telas grandes e um para telas pequenas):

```
<div class="menu-tela-grande hide-on-med-and-down">...</div>
<div class="menu-tela-pequena hide-on-med-and-up">...</div>
```

No plugin Materialize, a classe `hide-on-med-and-down` esconde o menu grande em telas pequenas, enquanto a classe `hide-on-med-and-up` esconde o menu pequeno em telas grandes ([Fonte](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html)).

**Um Bônus(tá mais pra dica):**

Recomendo o uso desse plugin pois facilita bastante o trabalho(eu mesmo uso ele muito), mas se você só quer fazer o menu mesmo, pode utilizar o mesmo conceito com `@media-queries`:

```
<div class="menu-tela-grande">...</div>
<div class="menu-tela-pequena">...</div>
```

E no css:

```
.menu-tela-grande {
   // ...Seu estilo para este menu
}
.menu-tela-pequena {
   display:none; // Fica escondido por padrão
   // ...Seu estilo para este menu
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { // Quando a tela for 800px ou menor
     .menu-tela-grande {
        display:none; // Esconde o menu grande
     }
     .menu-tela-pequena {
        display:block; // Mostra o menu pequeno
     }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida comente.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou dar uma estudada no materialize.